# Microsoft Teams tab http/https does not send request

Tags: javascript, azure-functions, microsoft-teams

I want to create a Microsoft Teams Tab as a web application. I've got the initial setup up and running. (Using Yo Teams) Now I want to send a http(s) request to an Azure Function. So I added a post middleware
function to my *server.ts*, which should call the Function.

```js
    express.post("/createteamswiki", (req, res) => {
        https.request("my.function.url", { method : "POST" }, () => {
        });
        res.status(200);
        res.json("Oki");
    });
```

In my *WikiConfig.ts* I changed the save method to send the request. I tried to use vanilla-js and the modules: *http* and *https*. With vanilla-js the request gets sent but it is marked as *ERR_FAILED* in Chrome dev tools. The libraries do not send anything at all. So the success callback is never called and therefore *saveEvent.notifySuccess();* is not called either. So the config window stays and reports an error.

```ts
    public async componentWillMount() {
            this.updateTheme(this.getQueryVariable("theme"));
    
            if (await this.inTeams()) {
                microsoftTeams.initialize();
    
                microsoftTeams.getContext((context: microsoftTeams.Context) => {
                    this.setState({
                        value: context.entityId
                    });
                    this.updateTheme(context.theme);
                    microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);
                    microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess();
                });
    
                microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler((saveEvent: microsoftTeams.settings.SaveEvent) => {
                    // Calculate host dynamically to enable local debugging
                    const host = "https://" + window.location.host;
                    microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
                        contentUrl: host + "/sharepointWikiTab/?name={loginHint}&tenant={tid}&group={groupId}&theme={theme}",
                        websiteUrl: host + "/sharepointWikiTab/?name={loginHint}&tenant={tid}&group={groupId}&theme={theme}",
                        suggestedDisplayName: "Sharepoint Wiki",
                        removeUrl: host + "/sharepointWikiTab/remove.html?theme={theme}",
                        entityId: this.state.value
                    });
                    microsoftTeams.getContext((context: microsoftTeams.Context) => {
                        this.setState({
                            value: context.teamSiteUrl || ""
                        });
                        https.request("https://" + window.location.host + "/createteamswiki?code=gM6t7bov41tkw1ZTxGZUasY1WQH7UgrONp4OyoVzaYaFtFBTBwZcRQ==&team=" + context.teamSiteUrl, (res) => {
                            this.setState({
                                value: "Awesome it works..."
                            });
                            saveEvent.notifySuccess();
                        });
                    });
                    // saveEvent.notifySuccess();
                });
            } else {
            }
        }
```

I can't find any reason why it behaves that way, since the request calls the node.js server, which is serving the http files successfully.

Comment: I believe this is something caused due to cross origin request. Can you check your request header and see if the CORS is enabled and also check the url is added in validDomain[] array in manifest .

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT you are right. It was missing in the validDomain array.

Comment: Good to know issue is resolved

Comment: Please mark this question closed by accepting the answer

Comment: **Thank You** for accepting answer, this will help others in the community with similar question. Could you please spare one min to let us know how we did by clicking on **[this feedback link](https://aka.ms/DevSupportFeedback)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is something caused due to cross origin request. Can you check your request header and see if the CORS is enabled and also check the url is added in validDomain[] array in manifest